# DELETE Representational State Transfer in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a project based in Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework. The version of the Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework is 3.2.8 deployed on a WebLogic Server Version: 12.1.2.0.0

I have this piece of code in my JSP

```
<button id="deleteImageButtonId165850" class="btn btn-primary"  type="submit" >Delete Image</button>
<script>
$('#deleteImageButtonId165850').click(function(){$('#serviceFormId').attr('action', 'http://127.0.0.1:7001/devices/newdesign/manage/application/service/image/del/165850');
$('#serviceFormId').attr('method', 'delete');});
</script>
```

and my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/newdesign/manage/application/service/image/del/{imageId}",
                              "/newdesign/manage/application/service/image/del/{imageId}/" }, method = { RequestMethod.DELETE })
    public String deleteServiceImage(@ModelAttribute("serviceForm") ServiceForm serviceForm, @PathVariable Long imageId,
                                    HttpServletRequest request, Model model) throws Exception {
..
}
```

But when I click in the button I got a

```
Request method 'GET' not supported
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML Forms do only support GET and POST.
You have to do the DELETE in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Test following code

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/newdesign/manage/application/service/image/del/{imageId}",
                              "/newdesign/manage/application/service/image/del/{imageId}/" }, method = { RequestMethod.POST })
    public String deleteServiceImage(@ModelAttribute("serviceForm") ServiceForm serviceForm, @PathVariable Long imageId,
                                    HttpServletRequest request, Model model) throws Exception {
..
}
```